# Scrapy crawled 0 page 0 item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I create a crawler using scrapy to scrape data from Indeed, which expected to return job title, company, location, description, qualification into a csv file. But i ran into problem: it not return any results, i dont know what the problem. I am a newbie to scrapy and web scraping.

**My spider code**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'Job'

  def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = 'https://vn.indeed.com/q-data-engineer-intern-vi%E1%BB%87c-l%C3%A0m.html'
    headers = { 
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
        }
    yield scrapy.Request(url = start_urls, headers = headers, callback = self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
    job_detail = response.css('h2.jobTitle > a.jcs-JobTitle::attr(href)').extract()
    for link in job_detail:
      yield response.follow(url = link, callback = self.parse2)

  def parse2(self, response):

    items = dict()

    job_title = response.css('h1.jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title > span::text').extract_first()
    company = response.css('div[data-testid="inlineHeader-companyName"] > a::text').extract_first()
    location = response.css('div[data-testid="jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-companyLocation"] > span::text').extract_first()
    job_description = response.css('div#jobDescriptionText > p::text').extract_first()
    qualification = response.css('div#jobDescriptionText > div:nth-child(6) > div::text').extract_first()
    pluses = response.css('div#jobDescriptionText > div:nth-child(10) > div::text').extract_first()
    items['title'] = job_title
    items['company'] = company
    items['location'] = location
    items['description'] = job_description
    items['qualification'] = qualification
    items['pluses'] = pluses

    yield items


process = CrawlerProcess(settings={'FEEDS': {'dataJob.csv':{'format':'csv'}}})
process.crawl(JobSpider)
process.start()
```

**My log file**

```
INFO:scrapy.utils.log:Scrapy 2.11.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.11.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
INFO:scrapy.utils.log:Versions: lxml 4.9.4.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.2, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0], pyOpenSSL 23.3.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023), cryptography 41.0.7, Platform Linux-6.1.58+-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.4.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.2, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0], pyOpenSSL 23.3.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023), cryptography 41.0.7, Platform Linux-6.1.58+-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
INFO:scrapy.addons:Enabled addons:
[]
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/request.py:254: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)
DEBUG:scrapy.utils.log:Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
INFO:scrapy.extensions.telnet:Telnet Password: 6d140ec38f893d8a
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 6d140ec38f893d8a
INFO:scrapy.middleware:Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
INFO:scrapy.crawler:Overridden settings:
{}
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
INFO:scrapy.middleware:Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
INFO:scrapy.middleware:Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
INFO:scrapy.middleware:Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Spider opened
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
INFO:scrapy.extensions.logstats:Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO:scrapy.extensions.telnet:Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): publicsuffix.org:443
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): publicsuffix.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://publicsuffix.org:443 "GET /list/public_suffix_list.dat HTTP/1.1" 200 83770
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://publicsuffix.org:443 "GET /list/public_suffix_list.dat HTTP/1.1" 200 83770
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (403) <GET https://vn.indeed.com/q-data-engineer-intern-vi%E1%BB%87c-l%C3%A0m.html> (referer: None)
2024-01-24 00:41:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://vn.indeed.com/q-data-engineer-intern-vi%E1%BB%87c-l%C3%A0m.html> (referer: None)
INFO:scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror:Ignoring response <403 https://vn.indeed.com/q-data-engineer-intern-vi%E1%BB%87c-l%C3%A0m.html>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2024-01-24 00:41:18 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://vn.indeed.com/q-data-engineer-intern-vi%E1%BB%87c-l%C3%A0m.html>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Closing spider (finished)
2024-01-24 00:41:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO:scrapy.extensions.feedexport:Stored csv feed (0 items) in: dataJob.csv
2024-01-24 00:41:18 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (0 items) in: dataJob.csv
INFO:scrapy.statscollectors:Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 333,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7899,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.382056,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 0, 41, 18, 48488, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 12643,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'memusage/max': 139415552,
 'memusage/startup': 139415552,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 0, 41, 17, 666432, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-01-24 00:41:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 333,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7899,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.382056,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 0, 41, 18, 48488, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 12643,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'memusage/max': 139415552,
 'memusage/startup': 139415552,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 0, 41, 17, 666432, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Spider closed (finished)
2024-01-24 00:41:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

i use the same framework with the web books.toscrape.com and it run normally. can someone explain the error for me

thanks for help

i ran the code on both vscode and ggcolab but it returned the same result

Comment: The website you're trying to crawl thinks you're a robot (which you are) and is refusing to talk to you.

Comment: can u recommend me some solution to this problem. in my initial code, i didnt add the headers user_agent and didnt get the error 403, but the spider also crawled 0 pages, do i need to use scrapy splash also?

Comment: Most sites have a page called robots.txt which have policies on web scraping. You can look at indeed's here: https://www.indeed.com/robots.txt  . They block the spider from scraping their data. But on books.toscrape it works fine because that's designed to practice web scraping. You can go to the settings file and change ROBOTSTXT_OBEY to False to ignore the robots.txt file.

Answer (score -1):

firstly, if you look at DevTools, then your url should be followed by a post request, if I'm not mistaken. Secondly, cloudflare is on the site, it is a very popular system for protecting sites from DDoS attacks and as a result of parsing. Try going to the curlconverter website and paste the url from your request there. If it helps, then as an option, take cookies from the browser and use them in Scrapy.